# Printing numbers 1 to 100 C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I am new here and in C# and I dont't know how to figure out that example..Printing numbers 1 to 100 that way "100, 1, 2, 99, 98, 3, 4, 97,....52, 49, 50, 51". I have a course work and should write it befoure 25.10..Thank you all!

Comment: please provide more details of what you are trying to accomplish, what you have tried, and what specifically isn't working as you expect.

Comment: First step: describe how you get that particular list. Just in your favorite spoken language

Comment: It seems like one of hackerrank problems, but the pattern of printing the numbers is not clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (int i = 1; i < 51; i+=2)
{
    Console.WriteLine(101-i);
    Console.WriteLine(i);
    Console.WriteLine(1+i);
    Console.WriteLine(100-i);
}
```

EDIT: just i want to add that i use (1+i) // (100-i) because if I use i-- or i++ inside the writeline, it will execute the ++ or -- after the print message

Comment: thanks a lot :) now I realise what's the idea is..

Comment: I dont know how..

Comment: @ФатиСахатчиева mark the tick ✔️(check mark) on the answer that helps you!  also there is an arrow that if you click up it will give us points!

Comment: thaks I find it...but I tried to give points but nothing happends..

Comment: @FatmaSahatchieva that's probably a cause of your reputation, once you get enought reputation, making good questions / answers, you will unlock new benefits! Hope it helps you! and thanks! have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

By using a `lower` and a `upper` variable and a while-loop, you can do it stright forward without any calculations:

```cs
int lower = 1, upper = 100;
while (lower < upper) {
    Console.WriteLine(upper--);
    Console.WriteLine(lower++);
    Console.WriteLine(lower++);
    Console.WriteLine(upper--);
}
```